# Overriding virtual method in type with conversion method

Tags: c#, .net

When I write  `Console.WriteLine( new Point (1,1));`  it doesn't call method `ToString`. But it converts object to `Int32`, and write it to console. But why? It seems as it ignores overridden method `ToString`.

```
struct Point
{
    public Int32 x;
    public Int32 y;

    public Point(Int32 x1,Int32 y1)
    {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
    }

    public static Point operator +(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return new Point(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y); 
    }


    public static implicit operator Int32(Point p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Converted to Int32");
        return p.y + p.x;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("x = {0}  |  y = {1}", x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `Int32` inherit from `Object`, conversion `Point` -> `Int32` is more specific than `Point` -> `Object`, so that `Console.WriteLine(Int32)` preferred over `Console.WriteLine(Object)`.

Comment: What is the actual output of `Console.WriteLine(new Point(1,1));`? [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx) it should call `ToString()` on the object being passed. Are you sure it's using your `Point` struct and not the  default `System.Drawing.Point` struct?

Comment: @sab669 - What could happen is that the compiler first does the implicit conversion, and then calls the `WriteLine(int)` overload, as opposed to the `WriteLine(object)` one, because language lawyer level reasons.

Comment: @ sab669  Yes, I am sure. Because it calls my conversion method to Int32. It writes to console : "Converted to Int32"

Comment: @millimoose Ah, I see what you mean. Yea PetSerAl is probably correct then.

Comment: I'd say the fix here is to not use the implicit conversion. Implicit conversions should, in my opinion, be used very sparingly, and only when the result of the conversion is as equivalent as possible to the original object. This is clearly not the case here, and you're just introducing a massive source of confusion as to the meaning of your code if the conversion can happen invisibly in who knows how many contexts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is due to implicit conversion to `Int32` *(As you probably know)*.

`Console.WriteLine` has many overloads which takes `String`, `Object` and others including `Int32`.

Since `Point` is implicitly convertible to `Int32` the `int` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70x4wcx1(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Console.WriteLine` is used, which does the implicit casting as well.

This can be fixed by:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Point(1, 1).ToString());
Console.WriteLine((object)new Point(1, 1));
```

You can find more about it in [Overload Resolution in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx).

> Otherwise, the best function member is the one function member that is
>   better than all other function members with respect to the given
>   argument list, provided that each function member is compared to all
>   other function members **using the rules in [Section 7.4.2.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338(v=vs.71).aspx)**.

Which further has:

[7.4.2.2 Better function member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338(v=vs.71).aspx)

> for each argument, the **implicit conversion** from AX to PX is not
>   worse than the implicit conversion from AX to QX, and

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the implicit conversion in your struct type i.e. the following lines:

```
public static implicit operator Int32(Point p)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Converted to Int32");
    return p.y + p.x;
}
```

So the compiler is considering your Point type as an integer by invoking the above implicit conversion method.

To fix this, you need to either remove the implicit conversion from your type or put a ToString() method while doing Console.WriteLine()

This should fix your issue. Hope this helps.

Best